# three column layout, column spacing

Tags: css, html

I was left to work with a three column layout and I don't know how to put some spacing between two columns: center column (content) and right column (div id = "side-gal"). Sample site is here http://jsfiddle.net/Taw4P/ Yellow is side-gal, center blue is content

What I want is the empty space like I have on the left side of webpage, between div id = "side-nav" and content. Doing this here was easy, I just reduced side-nav's width.
On the right side it doesn't work like this.

So, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `padding:0 10px;` to `margin:0 10px;` on `#side-gal`